# how do I prevent other elements from being affected by overflow hidden?

Tags: css, overflow, z-index, css-position

I have a parent element that has dynamic text in it that needs to be confined into a certain area. I had users that where writing sentences without using spaces (example:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy etc...) This was breaking the structure of my styled text area.

```
#ProfileCommentBody{ width:500px;  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333333; margin:15px 0px 0px 20px; float:left; background-color:#EAF7FB; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
```

I used `overflow:hidden`,as you can see above in the css code, and it solved the problem but created a new problem. I have another another element that is a image that is absolutely positioned that completes the style of my speech bubble ( the above element is the speech bubble) and when I have the above element on `overflow:hidden` it make that image disappear. I have tried z-index and that does not work.

```
.ProfileCommentTail{background:url(images/speechBubbleTail.png) no-repeat top left; width:15px; height:10px; position:absolute; top:20px; left:-15px;}
```

Is there a different option to use besides `overflow:hidden` or is there something I can do to counteract the unwanted part of what the `overflow:hidden` is doing?

html structure:

```
 <div id='ProfileCommentBody' class='round_10px'>
        <div id='CommentNameProfile'>
            <div class='ProfileCommentTail'>&nbsp;</div>
                <a href='http://www.blahblahblah.org/Profile.php?id=<?php echo $poster->id; ?>'>
                    <?php echo $poster->first_name. " ". $poster->last_name; ?> says...
                </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of an imgage of what it is doing now,which is wrong (missing speech bubble tail to the right of the polaroid, and the left of the speech bubble) overflow:hidden is causing this to disappear, but fixing another problem I was having:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cysticlife.org](https://www.cysticlife.org/styles/images/missing_tail.png))</sub>

here is what it is SUPPOSED to look like, notice the tiny blue speech bubble tail connected to the speech bubble:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cysticlife.org](https://www.cysticlife.org/styles/images/proper_tail.png))</sub>

Comment: why do you need overflow-hidden for? can you make another wrapper over #ProfileCommendBody and make ProfileCommentTail a child of that, so it's a sibling of ProfileCommentBody, then put position relative on that new wrapper? if you are using overflow to clear floats then change it to a clearfix method.

Comment: @meder, there is a a wrapper over #ProfileCommentBody and naturally ProfileCommentTail is a child of that. I am using the overflow:hidden to prevent over 100 characters of text without spacing breaking my speech bubble. I'm open to another alternative other than overflow:hidden. And yes I have the clearfix stuff taken care of elsewhere

Comment: it would help if you posted your html structure or include a demo, then.

Comment: I'm just gonna edit this with the div structure and a visual reference of how its supposed to look and what it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="blah">
     <div class='ProfileCommentTail'>&nbsp;</div>
     <div id='ProfileCommentBody' class='round_10px'>
        <div id='CommentNameProfile'>
                <a href='http://www.blahblahblah.org/Profile.php?id=<?php echo $poster->id; ?>'>
                    <?php echo $poster->first_name. " ". $poster->last_name; ?> says...
                </a>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is what I meant by my initial comment. CSS such as:

```
#blah { position:relative; }
```

Then again, because there is no layout/design/comp links it's hard to see what you are describing. I suggest posting visual details for visual problems.

Comment: okay yeah, I'm gonna add images now, one that is broken, and one that looks how it is supposed to look. I tried what your answer is btw. And thanks again for all of your help

Comment: Just thought you would be interested to know I figured it out. I took the tail <div> completely out of the structure,put it right underneath it, and absolutely positioned it from there.

Comment: I think that's what I meant in one way or another, but cheers.